# Check if array is nil / or has been loaded in Swift / iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

What is the best practice to check if an array of objects has been loaded in Swift?

Say, if I declare an array in a class, and it is lazily loaded. Apple's docs say the array declaration / initialization is something like

```
var events = [Event]()
```

I suppose the above means the array is already initialized (ie. not nil).

Then, I need a function like:

```
func getEvents() -> [Event] {
    // check if array is nil, and if so, load the events (not: which could be 0 events)
    return events
}
```

In Java, I would declare something like

```
ArrayList<Event> events;

public ArrayList<Event> getEvents() {
   if(!events) { // null means never been loaded
       events = new ArrayList<Event>();
       events = loadEvents(); // load the events, which could be zero
   }
}
```

What is the best practice to code the equivalent in Swift?

Comment: Note: it is not about checking if the array is empty, its purpose is to lazily load the events. Even after loaded, the events count can still be zero, and in this case it should not load again.

Comment: A variable of type `[Event]` (array of events) cannot be nil. A variable of type `[Event]?` (optional array of events) can.

Comment: Your java code is wrong. Looking at the signature it should return `ArrayList<Event>` but the `getEvents` method hasn't a return statement. I don't think it will compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Lazy Stored Property

In Swift you can declare a **lazy stored property**: it does exactly what you need.

```
struct Event { }

class Foo {
    lazy var events: [Event] = { self.loadEvents() }()

    private func loadEvents() -> [Event] {
        print("Loading events")
        return [Event(), Event(), Event()]
    }
}
```

We associated a closure to the `events` property. The closure defines how the `events` property should be populated and will be **executed only when the property is used**.

```
let foo = Foo()
print(foo.events) // now the events property is populated
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may experience an Array in these ways:

```
var vect = [String]()
 if vect.isEmpty {
    print ("true")
 }else{
    print("false")
 }
```

Or

```
func ceck()->Void{
    guard !vect.isEmpty else{
       print ("true")
       return // return, break, or another logic this is example
    }
}
```